# Issue retrieving key error not in index for reading from csv file for plotting

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Using below code to generate a stackedbar line graph however plotting the graph throws error. I tried to figure out the issue but could not. I checked csv file has row name Cat1 but still it throws error.

Code

```
 xtick=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25]
 data = pd.read_csv("C:/Graphs/data.csv")
 data[['Cat1','Cat2','Cat3']].plot(kind='bar', width = width,stacked=True,color=colors,figsize=(6.5, 
  3))
plt.ylabel("Latency (ms)")
plt.ylim(0, 75000)
data['Output_data'].plot(secondary_y=True,color='darkslategrey',marker='o',MarkerSize=2)
ax = plt.gca()
plt.xlim([-width, len(data['Cat3'])-width])
plt.ylim(0, 6)
plt.ylabel("Output-data")
```

data.csv file

```
Cat1    Cat2    Cat3    Output_data
12.97   699.52  230 12.545
38.99666667 673.4933333 5010    12.545
110.73  601.76  5010    3.137
134.5966667 577.8933333 1250    6.273
165.69  546.8   2500    6.273
```

Error

```
   data[['Cat1','Cat2','Cat3']].plot(kind='bar', width = width,stacked=True,color=colors,figsize=(6.5, 3))
   KeyError: "['Cat1'] not in index"
```

Comment: is that the real csv file? if it's tab-separated you should specify the separator in read_csv()

Comment: try `data.loc[['Cat1','Cat2','Cat3']]`

Comment: @frab, thanks yes its real csv file but I have uploaded just a sample data

Comment: Thanks @LukasSchmid, I tried retrieving KeyError: "None of [Index(['Cat1', 'Cat2', 'Cat3'], dtype='object')] are in the [index]"

Comment: You might wanna `print(data)` then, since it's not what you expect it to be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify the read function call to:

```
pd.read_csv("C:/Graphs/data.csv", sep="\t")
```